# Reverse root java

Tags: java

[This is a problem set](http://acm.timus.ru/problem.aspx?space=1&num=1001&locale=en)

This is my realization it works, but i get wrong answer on acm.timus.ru

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SqrtBack{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);

        long[] arr = new long[131072];
        while(in.hasNextLong()){
            arr[count] = in.nextLong();
            count++;
        }

        for(int i = arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
            System.out.printf("%.4f%n", (Math.sqrt(arr[i])));

        }
        out.flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Any rounding that must take place?

Comment: nope it should be without rounding

Comment: A couple of sample data/result pairs would be useful

Comment: two things, why are you setting up `out` if you just flush the stream and not write to it? And `System.out.printf` prints everything after each other, maybe you want to add a line break?

Comment: @ThomasJungblut `%n` adds a `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are always printing 131072 values even though the input could be fewer... Change your loop to:

```
for(int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--) ...
```

*Note: Always try with the sample data when doing problems like this. In this case you would see the problem directly..*